# Setting up a python screen scraper that could work on Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, screen-scraping

I am looking to setup a automated screen scraper that will run on Google app engine using python. I want it to scrape the site and put the specified results into a Entity in app engine. I am looking for some directions on what to use. I have seen beautifulsoup but wonder if people could recommend anything else that could run on Google App engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html) runs fine on App Engine (just make sure to use 3.0.8, not the iffy 3.1.0). The main alternative, I think, would be [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) -- I haven't tries it on App Engine but I believe it does run there (quite slowly -- if that's a problem I think you need to stick with BeautifulSoup), e.g. [this service](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-html-whitelist/) runs on App Engine and is based on html5lib.

Comment: Ahh ok Beautifulsoup it is have you seen any good code examples of Beautifulsoup setup and posting to an entity on app engine

Comment: @cozza, it all depends on what info you want to scrape and store -- I suggest opening another question in which you specify that.

Comment: I took your advice and reposted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406428/i-want-to-scrape-a-site-using-gae-and-post-the-results-into-a-google-entity

Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I have had good (although slow) results using mechanize and BeautifulSoup. In fact, to save code space on Google App Engine, I use the (old) version of BeautifulSoup included in mechanize.

I have mechanize in a zip file, `mechanize.zip`. The index of this zip file looks like:

```
mechanize/
mechanize/__init__.py
mechanize/_auth.py
mechanize/_beautifulsoup.py
mechanize/_clientcookie.py
... etc
```

Then in my Python code,

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'mechanize.zip')

import mechanize
from mechanize._beautifulsoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

The other choice is `lxml`, but it uses C code and so does not work on GAE.

Comment: OK I really need it to run on GAE

Comment: The new GAE (Nov, 2011) supports lxml. See the 3rd-party libraries [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/newin27.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have used BeautifulSoup with great success parsing HTML.  Problem is that's all BeautifulSoup does, is parse the HTML.  I ended up writing all the http interactions using urlfetch.

To web-scrape my target I need a full fledged code driven browser that can execute javascript on my target site's pages.  I think I'm having to dump the python app and go java so I can use HTMLUnit - prototyping underway. - mattb