# I want to scrape a site using GAE and post the results into a Google Entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, screen-scraping

I want to scrape this URL : https://www.xstreetsl.com/modules.php?searchSubmitImage_x=0&searchSubmitImage_y=0&SearchLocale=0&name=Marketplace&SearchKeyword=business&searchSubmitImage.x=0&searchSubmitImage.y=0&SearchLocale=0&SearchPriceMin=&SearchPriceMax=&SearchRatingMin=&SearchRatingMax=&sort=&dir=asc

Go into each of the links and extract out various pieces of information e.g. permissions, prims etc then post the results into a Entity on google app engine.

I want to know the best way to go about it?

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For normalizing HTML using a pure Python library I have had better experiences with [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) than BeautifulSoup.

However you just want to extract simply structured information, which doesn't actually require normalizing the HTML. I have a few scraping apps on Google App Engine which use [my own xpath library](http://code.google.com/p/webscraping/source/browse/xpath.py) that works with raw HTML.
Or you can use regular expressions for one off jobs.

Answer (score 3):

There are several nice screen scraping libraries you can use in Python.

Perhaps the easiest to knock up an advanced scraper with is [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).  It relies on [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) to implement the main engine but provides a very easy to use interface for implementing custom scraping code.

Otherwise you can look at doing it more manually with something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), or [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) which provides a "mechanical" browser implementation.

BeautifulSoup and Mechanize should both work out of the box on App Engine - it provides a wrapper around httplib and urllib that uses urlfetch as a backend. Only scrapy will be problematic, due to its use of twisted. [thanks to Nick Johnson for the update].

Comment: GAE provides the urlfetch module as a way to bypass the socket opening restriction.

Comment: @gnibbler: thats good to know: I guess the issue is that it will no work out of the box with any of the frameworks I listed so it would mean writing something from the ground up.  BeuatifulSoup could still be used to process the results though.  Thanks for the heads-up +1.

Comment: you can still use urllib2 on GAE but it is then wrapped around urlfetch, with some functionality removed

Comment: BeautifulSoup and Mechanize should both work out of the box on App Engine - it provides a wrapper around httplib and urllib that uses urlfetch as a backend. Only scrapy will be problematic, due to its use of twisted.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: really good to know.  I may try this myself at some point.

Comment: @jkp Perhaps you could update your reply so it doesn't say you're out of luck in the last paragraph, then?

Comment: @Nick Johnson: updated, credited you with the find.  Thanks again. +1